# SQl query output

Tags: database-theory, databases

Consider the table employee(empId, name, department, salary) and the two queries Q1 ,Q2 below. Assuming that department 5 has more than one employee, and we want to find the employees who get higher salary than anyone in the department 5, which one of the statements is TRUE for any arbitrary employee table?

Q1 :

Select e.empId

```
    From employee e
 Where not exists
    (Select * From employee s where s.department = “5” and 
                                    s.salary >=e.salary)
```

Q2
   Select e.empId

```
 From employee e
 Where e.salary > Any
(Select distinct salary From employee s Where s.department = “5”)
```

(A) Q1 is the correct query

(B) Q2 is the correct query

(C) Both Q1 and Q2 produce the same answer.

(D) Neither Q1 nor Q2 is the correct query

My work:- I am stuck at the word "**anyone**". If by anyone it means that all employees of department 5 than Q1 is correct,but if by anyone it means "any" (at least one) then Q2 is correct.We have a function is SQl named as "any" and that function says at least one should satisfy condition.So i am relating anyone to that function.Please help in understanding it correctly

Comment: The title you have chosen is not well suited to representing your question. Please take some time to improve it; we have collected some advice [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/a/815/). Thank you!

Comment: Also, you need to give attribution for the parts you copied!

Answer (score 1):

In English, "higher salary than anyone in department 5" normally means "higher salary than everyone in department 5".